# Compute stepwise regresion Model containing intercept, linear terms, and all products of pairs of distinct predictors

Tags: r, regression, r-caret, mixed-models

I have a dataframe `df`

```
df<-structure(list(P = c(794.102395099402, 1299.01021921817, 1219.80731174175, 
1403.00786976395, 742.749487463385, 340.246973543409, 90.3220586792255, 
195.85557320714, 199.390867672674, 191.4970921278, 334.452413539092, 
251.730350291822, 235.899165861309, 442.969718728163, 471.120193046119, 
458.464154601097, 950.298132134912, 454.660729622624, 591.212003320456, 
546.188716055825, 976.994105334083, 1021.67000560164, 945.965200876724, 
932.324768081307, 3112.60002304117, 624.005047807736, 0, 937.509240627289, 
892.926195849975, 598.564015734103, 907.984807726741, 363.400837339461, 
817.629824627294, 2493.75851182081, 451.149000503123, 1028.41455932241, 
615.640039284434, 688.915621065535, NaN, 988.21297, NaN, 394.7, 
277.7, 277.7, 492.7, 823.6, 1539.1, 556.4, 556.4, 556.4), T = c(11.7087701201175, 
8.38748953516909, 9.07065637842101, 9.96978059247473, 2.87026334756687, 
-1.20497751697385, 1.69057148825093, 2.79168506923385, -1.03659741363293, 
-2.44619473778322, -1.0414166493637, -0.0616510891024765, -2.19566614081763, 
2.101408628412, 1.30197334094966, 1.38963309876057, 1.11283280896495, 
0.570385633957982, 1.05118063842584, 0.816991857384802, 8.95069454902333, 
6.41067954598958, 8.42110173395973, 13.6455092557636, 25.706509843239, 
15.5098014530832, 6.60783204117648, 6.27004335176393, 10.0769600264915, 
3.05237224011361, 7.52869186722913, 11.2970127691776, 6.60356510073103, 
7.3210245298803, 8.4723724171517, 21.6988324356057, 7.34952593890056, 
6.04325232771032, NaN, 25.990913731, NaN, 1.5416666667, 15.1416666667, 
15.1416666667, 0.825, 4.3666666667, 7.225, -2.075, -2.075, -2.075
), A = c(76.6, 52.5, 3.5, 15, 71.5, 161.833333333333, 154, 72.5, 
39, 40, 23, 14.5, 5.5, 78, 129, 73.5, 100, 10, 3, 29.5, 65, 44, 
68.5, 56.5, 101, 52.1428571428571, 66.5, 1, 106, 36.6, 21.2, 
10, 135, 46.5, 17.5, 35.5, 86, 70.5, 65, 97, 30.5, 96, 79, 11, 
162, 350, 42, 200, 50, 250), Y = c(1135.40733061247, 2232.28817154825, 
682.15711101488, 1205.97307573068, 1004.2559099408, 656.537378609781, 
520.796355544007, 437.780508459633, 449.167726897157, 256.552344558528, 
585.618137514404, 299.815636674633, 230.279491515383, 1051.74875971674, 
801.07750760983, 572.337961145761, 666.132923644351, 373.524159859929, 
128.198042456082, 528.555426408071, 1077.30188477292, 1529.43757814094, 
1802.78658590423, 1289.80342084379, 3703.38329098125, 1834.54460388103, 
1087.48954802548, 613.15010408836, 1750.11457900004, 704.123482171384, 
1710.60321283154, 326.663507855032, 1468.32489464969, 1233.05517321796, 
852.500007182098, 1246.5605930537, 1186.31346316832, 1460.48566379373, 
2770, 3630, 3225, 831, 734, 387, 548.8, 1144, 1055, 911, 727, 
777)), .Names = c("P", "T", "A", "Y"), row.names = c(NA, -50L
), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to do a stepwise regresion analysis including intercept, linear terms, and all products of pairs of distinct predictors. So far I have managed to do it but only with a fixed model effect with the package `caret` (see below)

```
Step <- train(Y~ P+T+A, data=df,
                           preProcess= c("center", "scale"),
                           method = "lmStepAIC",
                           trainControl(method="cv",repeats = 10), na.rm=T)
```

Does anyone know how I can compute a regression model with an intercept, linear terms, and all products of pairs of distinct predictors?

Comment: I can't find any mixed effects model function supported in caret. Check the [list](https://topepo.github.io/caret/modelList.html) on this link. Neither `lme4` or `lmer` are there. You can use a custom model with caret but using a mixed model there is no simple task as far as I can tell.

Comment: As the experts over at stats.stackexchange.com keep telling people: Don't use stepwise regression.

Comment: Alright. But is there a way I can use all possible interactions though between my variable?

Comment: @ Roland. So what should we use then?

Comment: Packages like `lme4` actually give you the deviance. If you only look at roughly one "class" of models, the number of parameters are calculable just from the model formula. Therefore, you could easily write a function  that estimates models with say `lmer()` and proceeds according to changes in the AIC or BIC, which are relatively simple functions of the deviance and the number of parameters. EDIT: I know this isn't much to go on, but your question isn't exactly detailed either.

Comment: @ SimonB. I have updated my question because what I want is a regression model which contains an intercept, linear terms, and all products of pairs of distinct predictors.

Answer (score 0):

```
Step <- train(Y~ (P+T+A)^2, data=df,
                           preProcess= c("center", "scale"),
                           method = "lmStepAIC",
                           trainControl(method="cv",repeats = 10), na.rm=T)
```